# Phalcon migration doesn't update database

Tags: php, migration, phalcon

I started to learn Phalcon framework and I've some problems with migrations:

I've create a User model with phalcon dev-tools and i've got that class :

```
<?php

class User extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {


    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $ID;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $Name;

    /**
     * Initialize method for model.
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource('User');
    }

    /**
     * Independent Column Mapping.
     */
    public function columnMap()
    {
        return array(
            'ID' => 'ID',
            'Name' => 'Name'
        );
    }

}
```

I've added a FirstName attribute like that :

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
public $FirstName;
```

And in columnMap method :

```
/**
 * Independent Column Mapping.
 */
public function columnMap()
{
    return array(
        'ID' => 'ID',
        'Name' => 'Name',
        'FirstName' => 'FirstName'
    );
}
```

And i've generated a migration and i run it but my User table is not up to date.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Show the code for the migration please.

Comment: I made a mistake. I didn't understand migrations are generated from database, not from models.

There is a way to generate database from models ? Like doctrine with Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for [phalcon migrations](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/migrations.html#migration-class-anatomy) using the phalcon dev tools

Using the provided link, you can generate up() and down() functions that can then be run from the command line using phalcon dev tools.

```
public function up()
{
    $this->morphTable(
        "products",
        array(
            "columns" => array(
                new Column(
                    "id",
                    array(
                        "type"          => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
                        "size"          => 10,
                        "unsigned"      => true,
                        "notNull"       => true,
                        "autoIncrement" => true,
                        "first"         => true,
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes I've checked migrations docs but there's a way generate the database from models class like symfony commands : doctrine:schema:update for example ?
Thanks for your help